# Linuxtrack installation issues

Tags: apt, software-center

When I perform a

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

I have gotten the following errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch
http://www.linuxtrack.eu/repositories/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://www.linuxtrack.eu/repositories/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://www.linuxtrack.eu/repositories/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
ones used instead.
```

Then I discovered (after simply trying to go to Linuxtrack.eu with my web browser) that Linuxtrack.eu currently redirects to https://github.com/uglyDwarf/linuxtrack . Down at the bottom of the page is a DOWNLOAD link:
 https://github.com/uglyDwarf/linuxtrack/wiki/Downloads .

**This appears to be an archive or NEW repository for Linuxtrack.**

For DEBIAN versions- such as Xubuntu 14.04, they give you the following link:

```
https://github.com/uglyDwarf/linuxtrack/wiki/New-Build-Linux-(Debian-based)
```

**OK, so my question is, how do I make apt-get to stop looking for Linuxtrack.eu, and instead look at the correct website? I'm assuming that I would need to uninstall something.**

Also, if I go into the Ubuntu Software Center, do a search for "Linuxtrack", it lists the software as a Metapackage, and even provides an install button. BUT, it also lists the developer website as

```
https://code.google.com/archive/p/linux-track/,
```

which if you click on it shows the following:

```
"Due to the comming shutdown of the Google code, the project was moved to the GitHub. The new project page is 
https://github.com/uglyDwarf/linuxtrack"
```

So I'm also assuming that Ubuntu's Launchpad ALSO needs to be updated so as to reflect the corrected links, etc.

**How do I make apt-get look for the correct links?**

Comment: I looked into /etc/apt and looked into the file "sources.list" using gedit.  I'm wondering, if I could just manually delete the lines that direct to Linuxtrack.eu , would doing that cause apt-get from looking for it?

Comment: Nothing to do with Launchpad, so I'm deleting that tag.  Launchpad does not necessarily control every entry in your local `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, and doesn't in this case.